# webassessor is already linked to unknown Trailhead account

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, trailhead, certification, webassessor

I want to link my webassessor account with the trailhead. Since this is the first time i will be linking a trailhead. i am facing some weird issue. my webassessor is already being linked to a trailhead which i have never used. the Trailhead user which is linked, have same first name as my name but a different last name. i am not able to link Trailhead account which i have created. i raised a case with salesforce but i did not get any response yet. i want to maintain certification before it expires. Can anyone help me with this?